How can I open a blob file on a new tab with Lightning Locker enabled?
I have enabled Lightning Locker and updated the API version to 61. After that window.open is no longer working. I'm trying to generate an output document:
var pdfName = this.caseDetails.caseno + '_' +
  this.caseDetails.modalno + '_Bench Repair Form';
console.log('::::test 942:::');
window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), "_blank");
console.log('::::test 944:::');
console.log('::::pdfName:::', pdfName);

// Save the PDF
doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf');
console.log('::::After save pdfName:::');
toattachPDF({
  passBlob: btoa(doc.output()), caseId: this.caseId,
  formName: pdfName
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})


Could you please paste the complete code for understanding the issue? Also you can try these changes in Locker Console

The SecureWindow instance (which replaces window) does not support opening blob files. What happens when you try to do so is that you get this error:

Error: SecureWindow.open supports http:, https:, mailto: schemes and relative urls.

Tried it with this snippet below in the Locker Console page:
const str = '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';
const b = new Blob([atob(str)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
console.log(b);
const url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
console.log(url);
window.open(url, "_blank");

The link generated by the URL.createObjectURL method starts with blob:https://.... So it is "blob" instead of "http", "https" or mailto or a relative URL.

By the looks of your snippet, it seems that you are also storing this file somewhere. If you are storing it in Salesforce as an attachment (a ContentDocument) then you can open the preview of the document instead.
